# D3. How do I act on the selected node and all parent nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a D3 tree diagram link this one... https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083 and can select a node fine. I want to be able to iterate over the parent nodes too, and set an attribute eg `d.MainBranch="Yes"`. 
The idea is I can right click, get a menu to pop up and then click "Mark as Main Branch". I've done the right click to get a popup menu. and can set `d.MainBranch="Yes"` on the current node like this...

```
function marAsMainBranch(d) {           
    d.mainBranch="Yes"; 
    update(d);
}
```

just lacking the ability to iterate over the parents :-(

Can anyone help?

Comment: The problem is that the data (https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4063550/flare.json) has the child references, there is no parent reference. I think that you're better off starting from the top of the tree and recursively iterating down it until you find the node that has been clicked, then marking all the parents on the way back up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this to set parent data and call recursively till no parent *(starting from the node which is acted)*:

```
function setInfoParent(d){
  d.mainBranch="Yes";
  if(d.parent){
    setInfoParent(d.parent);//call recursively itself till no parent.
  }
  console.log(d);
}
```

Then in click or right click action call `setInfoParent` something like this:

```
function click(d) {
  setInfoParent(d);//call to set all parents.
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}
```

Working fiddle [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/wJFuSkNuVc3tJaql6j14?p=preview)